# Cómo liberar la memoria para el atributo age

Tags: c, struct

Mi intención es liberar la memoria asignada para el atributo `age` de este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct TEST test;
struct TEST
{
    char* name;
    int* age;
};

test test_new (test*, char*, int);

int
main (void)
{
    test t;

    int age = 13;
    int* p_age = &age;
    test_new (&t, "", *p_age);

    printf ("Age [%i]\n",  *t.age);

    free (t.age);

    return 0;
}


test test_new (test* _test, char* _name, int _age)
{
    (*_test).age = (int *) malloc (1 * sizeof (int));
    (*_test).age = &_age;

    return (*_test);
}
```

Al comentar la línea donde libero `free (t.age);` me aparece en **valgrind** un recurso sin tratar:

```
==17683==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,028 bytes allocated
```

Al asignarle el código para la liberación de recurso me aparece esto:

```
$ ./main7
Age [13]
*** Error in `./main7': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffff2b0bebc ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777f5)[0x7f83261f17f5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8038a)[0x7f83261fa38a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f83261fe58c]
./main7[0x400686]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f832619a840]
./main7[0x400559]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:13 2745                               /home/ubuntu/main7
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:13 2745                               /home/ubuntu/main7
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:13 2745                               /home/ubuntu/main7
02305000-02326000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f8320000000-7f8320021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8320021000-7f8324000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8325f64000-7f8325f7a000 r-xp 00000000 00:19 12664                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8325f7a000-7f8326179000 ---p 00016000 00:19 12664                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8326179000-7f832617a000 rw-p 00015000 00:19 12664                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f832617a000-7f832633a000 r-xp 00000000 00:19 12626                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f832633a000-7f832653a000 ---p 001c0000 00:19 12626                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f832653a000-7f832653e000 r--p 001c0000 00:19 12626                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f832653e000-7f8326540000 rw-p 001c4000 00:19 12626                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f8326540000-7f8326544000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8326544000-7f832656a000 r-xp 00000000 00:19 12598                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f832674a000-7f832674d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8326768000-7f8326769000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8326769000-7f832676a000 r--p 00025000 00:19 12598                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f832676a000-7f832676b000 rw-p 00026000 00:19 12598                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f832676b000-7f832676c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff2aee000-7ffff2b0f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffff2b7b000-7ffff2b7e000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff2b7e000-7ffff2b80000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Ahora si tomo y comento `//free (t.age);` y coloco `free (t.name);` y en el constructor que quede de esta forma:

```
test test_new (test* _test, char* _name, int _age)
{
    (*_test).name = (char *) malloc (1 * sizeof (char));
    strcpy ((*_test).name, _name);

    return (*_test);
}
```

Todo camina a la maravilla, puedo observar cómo el recurso se libera de forma completa:

```
==17779==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,025 bytes allocated
```

¿Qué es lo que pasa aquí?

Inicialmente comenzé este ejercicio con `int* age;` en la estructura y en vista de estos errores le agregé otro tipo básico para verificar mi sospecha y resultó que tengo resultado exitoso en uno, pero en el otro no lo tengo.

Gracias por leer y comentar.

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas que te han proporcionado son correctas o solucionan tu problema deberías acostumbrarte a marcarlas como respuesta correcta pulsando en el icono **✓** que hay a la izquierda de la respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

El problema de tu primera prueba está en estas lineas:

```
(*_test).age = (int *) malloc (1 * sizeof (int));
(*_test).age = &_age;
```

En la primera linea pides memoria con malloc y guardas el puntero resultante
en `(*_test).age`, después, en la segunda linea lo sobreescribes con un puntero a _age
(que es una variable con almacenamiento automático), y ya no se puede acceder
al puntero devuelto por malloc, por lo que se produce una fuga de memoria (que
detecta valgrind).

Después en esta línea:

```
free (t.age);
```

free solo puede liberar la memoria de punteros devueltos por malloc o familia, así
que al usarlo con `t.age` exhibe comportamiento indefinido. En este caso, free muestra
un mensaje de error y termina el programa, pero podría pasar cualquier cosa.

Si quieres inicializar el puntero que devuelve malloc con la variable _age, deberías
desreferenciar `(*_test).age` y asignarle _age, de esta forma:

```
// NO, sobrescribe `(*_test).age` con un puntero a _age
(*_test).age = &_age;

// SI, desreferencia `(*_test).age` y le asigna _age
*((*_test).age) = _age;
```